# Android Development displaying and send lat and lon to database

Tags: java, android, mysql

i am working on a project that allows the user to add/update/delete records from a MySQL database. The app successfully uploads and retrieves all information from the database. I am trying to get the lat and long to be displayed itself as soon as i send the values from emulator control instead of the user having to manually put the values in themselves via a textfield which was how i originally programmed it to be. After they are displayed the values should be inserted into the database along with the other textfields values. I hope that makes sense.. Now when i send the values from the emulator control they are not being displayed in the textView and im not sure why? Any help would be highly appreciated.

UPDATE: This is where the lat and long views are being initialised and should be getting the values from the emulator control?

```
//Defining views
//private EditText editTextLatitude;
//private EditText editTextLongitude;
private EditText editTextTimeInserted;
private EditText editTextUserID;
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

private Button buttonAdd;
private Button buttonView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing views
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
    //editTextLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLat);
    //editTextLongitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLon);
    editTextTimeInserted = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTimeInserted);
    editTextUserID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserID);

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);

    //Setting listeners to button
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    }
 }

 public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));

  }
```

Comment: Other any other details? Can you narrow down and tell where you got? Is it coming to the client? Nobody wants to learn your complete code

Comment: It is showing the textViews when i run the application, but when i send the values of lat and long from the emulator they are not displaying them, keep a eye out for update above, I will narrow down the code for this @IliiazAkhmedov, Also i am very new to this so please bear with me if i don't get anything right away..

Answer (score 1):

Add in manifest.xml
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

```
// Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.

if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
    .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

[follow the link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)